# jQuery ajax call inside ajax response returning HTML rather than JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, highcharts

I am writing a simple viewer for time series data using HighCharts.  One problem that can happen is that the values can stop coming in for a period, then resume.  On my system those values do eventually make it into the database, I do not lose them, they are just delayed.  What I want on my UI is for it to scroll normally once per second as data is coming in (this if working fine).  If data stops, the UI should pause scrolling (this is also working).  If data availability resumes some time later, then I'd like the chart to do a "gap fill", i.e. populate the parts that it missed during the unavailable period.

That's what I'm trying to fix now.  I issue a synchronous $.ajax call to get the missing data, but the data returned is the HTML of the page itself, not JSON.  I've tested the server side call and it is returning JSON fine when called from a directly from a browser.  So can anyone see what is going wrong in my "gap fill" plotting?  See comment "data2 here is HTML not JSON for some reason" in the code below for where it's going wrong.

Thank you,
Virgil

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" http-equiv="content-type">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script>
function log(msg) {
    if ( window.console && window.console.log ) {
        console.log(msg)
    }
}

function pauseBtnHandler() {
    pauseChart = !pauseChart
    if (pauseChart) {
        $('#pauseBtn').val('Resume Display')
    }
    else {
        $('#pauseBtn').val('Pause Display')
    }
}

function timestampToLocaldate(timestamp) {
    return new Date(timestamp - TIMEZONE_OFFSET)
}

$(function () {
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false })
    pauseChart = false
    prevTimestamp = 0
    prevScroll = true
    dataStoppedTimestamp = false

    // get localtime offset in minutes, then convert to ms for use with charting
    offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset()
    TIMEZONE_OFFSET = -offset * 60 * 1000
    SAMPLE_PERIOD = 1000

    // Do an initial query to get the current latest timestamp (in ms since Epoch)
    jQuery.ajax({
         url:    '/mgmt/currentValues',
         success: function(data) {
                     now = data['timestamp'] * 1000 + TIMEZONE_OFFSET
                  },
         error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert('Error getting initial timestamp, defaulting time to now ' + thrownError)
            now = new Date().getTime()
         },
         async:   false
    });  

    var chart;
        $('#chart').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'spline',
                animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE

                backgroundColor:
                {
                    linearGradient: [0, 0, 0, 500],
                    stops: [
                        [0, 'rgb(160, 160, 160)'],
                        [1, 'rgb(0, 0, 0)']
                    ]
                },
                events: {
                    load: function() {
                        var series1 = this.series[0];
                        setInterval(function() {
                              $.get("mgmt/currentValues",function(data, status){
                                if (!pauseChart) {
                                    var timestamp = data['timestamp'] * 1000 + TIMEZONE_OFFSET

                                    // Only scroll the chart if a more recent value has come in
                                    dt = timestamp - prevTimestamp
                                    var scroll = (dt > 0)
                                    if (!scroll) {
                                        dataStoppedTimestamp = timestamp
                                    }

                                    // Determine if gap fill required
                                    if (prevScroll == false && scroll == true && dt > SAMPLE_PERIOD) {
                                        log('doing gapfill from ' + timestampToLocaldate(dataStoppedTimestamp) + ' to ' + timestampToLocaldate(timestamp))
                                        jQuery.ajax({
                                            url:'/mgmt/getdatafortimeperiod/%d/%d' % (dataStoppedTimestamp, timestamp),
                                            success: function(data2) {
                                                // data2 here is HTML not JSON for some reason
                                                log(data2)
                                                for (row2 in data2) {
                                                    var timestampGf = row2['timestamp'] * 1000 + TIMEZONE_OFFSET
                                                    series1.addPoint([timestampGf, row2['cpuPct']], false, true)
                                                }                
                                             },
                                             error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                                                alert('Error getting gapfill data ' + thownError)
                                             },
                                             async: false
                                        });  
                                    }

                                    series1.addPoint([timestamp, data['cpuPct']], scroll, true)
                                    log(timestampToLocaldate(timestamp) + ' ' + data['cpuPct'])
                                    prevTimestamp = timestamp
                                    prevScroll = scroll
                                }
                              });
                        }, SAMPLE_PERIOD);
                    }
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: 'PERFORMANCE DATA',
                 style: {
                    color: 'black',
                    fontWeight: 'bold',
                    fontSize: '1.5em',
                    fontFamily: 'Arial',
                 } 
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
                tickPixelInterval: 150,
                 labels: {
                    style: {
                        color: 'white',
                        fontFamily: 'Arial',
                    },
                }
            },
            yAxis: [{
                lineWidth: 1,
                min: 0,
                labels: {
                    style: {
                        color: 'white',
                        fontFamily: 'Arial',
                    },
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'CPU (%)',
                     style: {
                        color: 'white',
                        fontWeight: 'bold',
                        fontSize: '16px',
                        fontFamily: 'Arial',
                     }                  
                }
            }],
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                        str = '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                        Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', this.x) +'<br/>'+
                        Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 0);
                        return str;
                }
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: true,
                itemStyle: {
                    color: 'white',

                    font: 20,                           
                },

                backgroundColor: '#1C1C1C',
                margin: 30, 
                itemDistance: 22,
                symbolWidth:22,
                symbolHeight:16,            
            },
            exporting: {
                enabled: true
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'CPU %',
                color: '#FF0000',
                data: (function() {
                    // generate an initial array of data
                    var data = [],
                        time = now,
                        i;

                    for (i = -39; i <= 0; i++) {
                        data.push({
                            x: time + i * SAMPLE_PERIOD,
                            y: 0
                        });
                    }
                    return data;
                })()
            },
            ]
        });
    });

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="graph">
    <div id="chart" style="; height: 100%; margin: 0 auto; "></div>
    <div id="pauseButton">
         <input id="pauseBtn" type="submit" value="Pause Display" onclick="pauseBtnHandler();">
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try to add `dataType: "json"` in your ajaxsetup and see if that works

Comment: A very good suggestion, but the error persists.

Comment: Have you checked what actual url the ajax request is sent? Does your request makes it to the server method?

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem, pretty basic.  I was using Python style sprintf formatting to generate the gapfill URL.  Too much Python on my mind.